# The difference between local send size (-m) and send buffer size (-s) in netperf?

Tags: performance, networking, linux-kernel, bandwidth

I'm now using the netperf to do some bandwidth test on a Ubuntu machine.

I setup a netperf client and a netperf server in the same host. And I did some intra-host packet forwarding between the client and server.

However what I found that the default settings of netperf cannot fully leverage the intra-host bandwidth.

I used the iperf3 to do the intra-host packet forwarding bandwidth test before. And the bandwidth will usually be around 35 Gbps.

When I used the netperf to do the intra-host packet forwarding bandwidth test, the bandwidth I get will only be around 11 Gbps, which is too small when you consider about the intra-host packet forwarding bandwidth. Below is the output for the netperf test:
[image]

And what confused me in the netperf's output is the meaning of "Send Message Size". Is it packet size? But usually when we talk about packet size, we refer it to the MTU size or MSS size. So what is the actually meaning of the "Send Message Size" in netperf.

I also tried to change the number of "Send Message Size" to 128KB (131072B), which is equal to the "Recv Socket Size". This time the intra-host packet forwarding bandwidth will be around 35 Gbps, which is expected to fully utilize the intra-host bandwidth. So why the "Send Message Size" can affect the measurements of the bandwidth. It really make me feel confused. Could anyone give me some guidance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Send Message Size" is how many bytes are presented to the stack with any one "send" call.  The larger the send message size, the fewer the number of send calls necessary to put a given quantity of data into the stack.

Netperf's default for the send message size is to take the value of the send socket buffer (SO_SNDBUF) size at the time of the data socket's creation.  If you look on your linux system at:

sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_wmem

You will see the second value (which is the initial size) is 16384 bytes.  And if you look at:

sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_rmem

you will see the initial value for the receive socket bufffer (SO_RCVBUF) is 128K.

Iperf3's default send size is 128K

By default (unless one makes an explicit setsockopt() call for the socket buffer size), Linux will "autotune" the sizes of the socket buffers over the life of the connection.  What netperf displays is what they were at the start of the connection.  You can have it display what they were at the end of the connection by using the "omni output selectors"

$ netperf -- -O ? | grep -e "[LR]S[SR]_SIZE"
LSS_SIZE_REQ
LSS_SIZE
LSS_SIZE_END
LSR_SIZE_REQ
LSR_SIZE
LSR_SIZE_END
RSS_SIZE_REQ
RSS_SIZE
RSS_SIZE_END
RSR_SIZE_REQ
RSR_SIZE
RSR_SIZE_END

LSS = Local Socket Send
RSR = Remote Socket Receive
_REQ being the requested value
_END being the value at the end of the test